# How to show inputting text in other div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I wonder how could I show text from input, also in other div? I mean that I type a text in input, and it's also showing in other div.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: In what context do you want to use this? But jQuery is what you'll need

Comment: `keyup` event will be your clue. Try that and come here if you have any further doubts.

Comment: Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/2RwJJ/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#text').keypress(function(){
    $('#content').text($(this).val());
});
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wg2va/)

or you can use [AngulaJS](http://angularjs.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<input id='id' />
<div id='divId'></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('input#id').on('keyup',function(){
       $('div#divId').html(this.value);
       // you can use .text(this.value), if textbox value is not having html tags
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/ZS9U7/)

Comment: Better to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: Yes if I use `html tags` then `html()` is a good option.

Comment: The `change` event might be more appropriate to handle right click - paste as well

Comment: `change` doesn't trigger until the user leaves the field.

Comment: That is true. So maybe both?

Answer (score 1):

[Pure JS Version](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS9U7/1/)

HTML:

```
<input id='id' />
<div id='divId'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("id");
var div = document.getElementById("divId");

input.onkeyup = function()
{
    div.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

Comment: its not that jQuery is bad, but the devs should also learn using the Pure JS version. so my vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

**HTML Code:**

```
<form>
  <input id="target" type="text" value="">
</form>
<div id="other" style="border:1px">

</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
   $('#other').text($(this).val())
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/X8mHm/

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="inputVal"></p>

 <div id="divHTML"></div>
 <script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#inputVal').keyup(function(){
       $('#divHTML').html(this.value);
    });

});

 </script>
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/qj7J3/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

HTML

`<input type="text" id="copy" onkeyup="startCopyPaste()" />`
   `<div id="paste"></div>`

javscript

```
function startCopyPaste() {
    var copy = document.getElementById('copy');
    var paste = document.getElementById('paste');

    paste.innerHTML = copy.value;
}
```

see full code at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AhczG/1/)